# I want to fetch values from 2 textboxes and add them to mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to fetch values from 2 textboxes and add them to mysql database using PHP.
My HTML:

```
<form name='form' method='post'>
  Username:<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
   Password:<input type="text" id="password" name="password"/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" style="width:50%;padding:10px;">
```

And here goes the PHP:

```
<?php
     $username="";
     $pwd="";
     $pword="";
        try{
        global $username,$pwd;
        if ( ! empty($_POST['username']) && ! empty($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
         $pwd = $_POST['password'];
        }        
        $servername = "localhost";
        $conusername = "root";
        $conpassword = "";
        $dbname = "annapoorna";
        $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
        $sql='INSERT INTO users(username, password) values (:username,:password)';
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
        $sth->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':password'=>$pwd ));
        }

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
   ?>
```

But the values are not adding to the database. Why?

Comment: attribute `name` in missing in `input tag`

Comment: what's with the `global $username,$pwd;`? They're already in scope.

Comment: I had a function previously which I've removed now. They were outside it. That shouldn't affect, should it?

Comment: @Saty didn't get it. I'm new to PHP. Please explain.

Comment: To post value from form we need name attribute in input tag as `<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>`. And your really need to learn [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: Added the attribute like `<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>`

Comment: form action attribute missing in form

Answer (score 0):

Input values are received by php trougth `name` attr 
HTML code:

```
<form name='form' method='post'>
Username:<input type="text" id="username" name='username'/>
Password:<input type="text" id="password" name='password'/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" style="width:50%;padding:10px;">
```

`Global` not needed

PHP code:

```
<?php
 $username="";
 $pwd="";
 $pword="";
    try{
    if ( ! empty($_POST['username']) && ! empty($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
     $pwd = $_POST['password'];
    }        
    $servername = "localhost";
    $conusername = "root";
    $conpassword = "";
    $dbname = "annapoorna";
    $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
    $sql='INSERT INTO users(username, password) values (:username,:password)';
    $sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
    $sth->execute(array(':username'=>$user`enter code here`name,':password'=>$pwd ));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: for password we use `type="password"`

Answer (score 0):

A bit too long for a comment, but as it will probably help you to solve the problem: You should set up PDO to throw exceptions when something goes wrong. Now you are trying to catch them, but probably nothing gets thrown.

You can do that in the constructor:

```
$conn = new PDO(
    $dsn, 
    $conusername, 
    $conpassword, 
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
);
```

You should also enable error handling and display them all. You can do that by adding this to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Note that I assume that you have already added the missing `name` attributes in the form as mentioned in the comments.

Also note that you should hash and salt the password using for example [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), never store plain-text, encrypted or weakly hashed passwords.